# ViewPager - Changing the Up button Icon Depending on the Current Page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm attempting to change the up button icon depending on the current page in a ViewPager. For the first page I wish to display a cross icon and all subsequent pages to display the back arrow
I have attempted the following in each fragment:

```
@override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_some_icon_goes_here);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Unfortunately the icon does not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and based on the position of the selected page in view pager you can change the appropriate icon. check the below link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Let me know for any further help.